# Array being set to null in recursive method

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am attempting to write a spider using CasperJS used to parse pages and extract relevant links. The site in question features a hierarchical view of files and folders. I have written a recursive method to perform the navigation through the file structure, but after the first iteration of the method my array is returning null, even though function is running correctly. Any help identifying the problem would be really appreciated.

```
var processPage = function() {

    //Gather links
    var links = this.evaluate(function() { //links is the array being set to null
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");
        return Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(e) {
            //check link matches our white list
            var matchesWhitelist = false;

            var fileDescription = e.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
            console.log("span text:" + fileDescription);

            //begin checking
            if (fileDescription.indexOf('.mp3') != -1) matchesWhitelist = true;
            //if (fileDescription.indexOf('.wmv') != -1) .... etc

            //failing that is the link for a folder rather than a file
            var hrefLink = e.getAttribute("href");
            if (hrefLink.indexOf('folder-files') != -1) matchesWhitelist = true;

            if (matchesWhitelist) {
                console.log('match');
                console.log('Adding link: ' + hrefLink)
                return hrefLink;
            }
            else {
                console.log('no match');
            }
        });
    });

console.log("linkslength: " + links.length); // links will be null upon recursion

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

        //check link matches our 'whitelist'
        this.thenOpen("https://TLD" + links[i]).then(function() {
            this.echo("New URL: " + this.getCurrentUrl());

            //check for files
            if (this.exists(".fileDownload")) {
                //extract link
            } else {
                //assume that this is a 'folder' link and send to be processed for more links
                casper.then(processPage); //continue recursion
            };
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "`links` will be `null`"? Array.map always returns an array

Comment: On the first iteration console.log("linkslength: " + links.length) will return (as expected) "linkslength: 8" which is correct. On the second iteration the same line outputs: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'links.length') If I just pass links to console.log then it outputs null

Comment: Also, during the second iteration the Array.map inline function is running ok as I am getting the 'match' and 'Adding link' console outputs. It's very strange, it's like once the inline function exits links suddenly become out of scope.

Comment: What does `this.evaluate` do with your function?

Comment: this.evaluate is used by CasperJS to evaluate an expression in the remote page context. I'm a little vague on the details but as I understand without it I have no access to the remote page DOM. A better explanation is here: [link](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.evaluate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a reduced set.

This means you should use `.filter` instead of `.map`, and return a truthy value if you want to keep the link, and a falsey value if not.

```
return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(e) {

     //...

    if (matchesWhitelist) {
        console.log('match');
        console.log('Adding link: ' + hrefLink)
        return true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('no match');
    }
});
```

And if you don't need the logging, you would just return `matchesWhitelist`.

```
return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(e) {

     //...

    return matchesWhitelist;
});
```

So get rid of the logging, and you can reduce your filter to this.

```
return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(e) {

    return e.getAttribute("href").indexOf('folder-files') != -1 ||
           e.querySelector("span").innerHTML.indexOf('.mp3') != -1;
});
```

Comment: However, this does not map the elements to URLs - you need both

Answer (score 0):

Some items in the `links` array are `undefined`, because your mapping function does not return anything if `matchesWhitelist` is false.

Other issues: Not all links on a page need to contain a span. Accessing the `innerHTML` then would break your function. And: I can't see an array of already crawled pages. Any circular linking would lead your crawler in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could accept both of your answers, as they both were helpful in me getting to the source of the problem. I had been overcomplicating things, and the issue was solved by applying a filter first to reduce the set to just the elements I need, then performing a map so that I could return an array with just the links required. The code I ended up using was

```
var processPage = function() {
    var url;
    //Gather links
    var links = this.evaluate(function() {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");
        var filteredElementsList = Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(e) {

            //check link matches our white list

            var matchesWhitelist = false;

            var fileDescription = e.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
            console.log("span text:" + fileDescription);

            //begin checking
            if (fileDescription.indexOf('.mp3') != -1) matchesWhitelist = true;

            //failing that is the link for a folder rather than a file
            var hrefLink = e.getAttribute("href");
            if (hrefLink.indexOf('folder-files') != -1) matchesWhitelist = true;

            if (matchesWhitelist) {
                console.log('match');
                console.log('Adding link: ' + hrefLink)
            } else {
                console.log('no match');
            }

            return matchesWhitelist;
        });

        return Array.prototype.map.call(filteredElementsList, function(e) {
            return e.getAttribute("href");
        });
    });
```

The script works now and  and extracts every link i need. Thanks again for the help.